# How returning a string when using jitclass from numba?

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm trying to return a string when I call a function in a class that uses `jitclass` but I get an error:

```
numba.errors.InternalError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
cannot convert native const('Something') to Python object
[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'get_Names') for     instance.jitclass.myclass#3f2d488<A:float64,B:float64>)
[2] During: typing of call at <string> (3)
```

I'm using this code to test the function:

```
from numba import jitclass
from numba import boolean, int32, float64,uint8

spec = [('A' ,float64),
        ('B' ,float64)]

@jitclass(spec)
class myclass:

    def __init__(self,):
        self.A = 3.25
        self.B = 22.5

    def get_Names(self):
        return "Something"



mC = myclass()
print(mC.get_Names())
```

Does somebody know How I could return a string?

Comment: This is currently not supported in numba, nor are strings in general supported with nopython mode (writing as of version `0.36`)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But maybe there exists a work around. Maybe based on uint8 array or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort of work around this by using an array of bytes to represent the string, as shown below.

That said, I think this is pretty ugly/hard to maintain.  Assuming it fits the problem, I think you are better off using a plain python class with `jit` functions for speedups as necessary, or dropping into something like `cython` which has richer support for extension types.

```
from numba import jitclass, float64

SOMETHING = np.frombuffer(b"Something", dtype='uint8')

spec = [('A' ,float64),
        ('B' ,float64)]

def get_jitclass_str(val):
    return bytes(val).decode('utf-8')

@jitclass(spec)
class myclass:

    def __init__(self,):
        self.A = 3.25
        self.B = 22.5

    def get_Names(self):
        return SOMETHING
```

Usage

```
In [16]: mc = myclass()

In [17]: get_jitclass_str(mc.get_Names())
Out[17]: 'Something'
```

Comment: Sounds promising. Howevrer in the code you wrote. the string "Something" cannot be changed. In my script, the string are generated in situ. It is then a variable. Is it also possible to get a string that is modify inside myclass? My question was maybe not well explained.

Comment: If you want to return from a enumerated set of options, then yes, it is easy, just throw in some more globals.  If it is truly dynamically generated, then yes, still possible, but an even bigger hassle as you'll have to use the integer representation of bytes to build it up.